# Change all values with an absolute value less than 1 with 0

Tags: text-processing

I have a large file with a lot of rows and columns; the value of the contents are between -2 and 2. I'm interested in replacing values which, in their absolute value form, are less than; I want to replace them with 0. For example, if there's a -0.3 or 0.6 (abs value 0.3 and 0.6) I want to replace them with zeros. Anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: Can you post some lines of the file in question?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
  for (i=1; i<= NF; i++) {
    if($i < 1 && $i > -1) { $i=0; }
  }
  print }' file
```

... will get them with awk.

With sed (being careful not to keep the two expressions in this order, otherwise you end up with negative zeroes):

```
sed -e 's/-0\.[0-9]*/0/g' -e 's/0\.[0-9]*/0/g' file
```

Adding a solution, just for fun, in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# for extended pattern matching, to grab repeated [:digits:]
shopt -s extglob

# to prevent filename globbing
set -f

while read line
do
  # specifically left $line unquoted to allow splitting
  for f in $line
  do
    f=${f/-0.*([[:digit:]])/0}
    f=${f/0.*([[:digit:]])/0}
    printf "%s " $f
  done
  printf "\n"
done
```

Note that this adds a trailing space to each line; pipe it to `sed 's/ $//'` to remove the trailing space.

... and adding a shell/grep solution (that doesn't use any bash-isms), just for more fun:

```
set -f
while read line
do   
  # specifically left $line unquoted to allow splitting
  for f in $line
  do 
    echo $f | grep -q -E -- '-?0\.[[:digit:]]'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then   
      printf "0 "
    else   
      printf "%s " $f
    fi
  done
  printf "\n"
done
```

The `-q` flag silences grep's output; all we want is the return code. The `-E` flag enables '[:digit:]' instead of '[0-9]'.
Note that this also adds a trailing space to each line; pipe it to `sed 's/ $//'` to remove the trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/\S+/abs($&) < 1 ? 0 : $&/ge' < your-file
```

Here, `perl` will accept numbers like `0.123`, `-12e-4`, not hexadecimal or other notations (0x12 would be treated as 0 and 010 as 10, not 8).

Example:

```
$ echo "1.2  120e-4 0.001e4 -0.2" | perl -pe 's/\S+/abs($&) < 1 ? 0 : $&/ge'
1.2  0 0.001e4 0
```

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(sqrt($i^2)<1){printf "0 "}else{printf "%s ", $i}print ""}'
```

This should do what you want. (but it could not be portable and contains an unnecessary call to sqrt(). Jeff Schallers Answer is better.)

the `for`-loop loops over your tables columns, the `sqrt($i^2) <1` was your condition (`sqrt(x*x)` or `sqrt(x^2)` results in the absolute value of x) and the if-else-part prints `0` if the absolute value is smaller than `0.6` and if it's bigger, it prints the value of `$i` instead.

I hope it was what you wanted.

**Note**
If you want another field separator than `' '` you have to add additional options.
 [AWK-manual page -- http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_23.html](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_23.html)

Comment: For values less than one, the square is still less than one.  The call on `sqrt` is unnecessary.  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) is a better source for discussing awk (saves discussion about what features are portable).

Comment: sqrt(x*x) = y (y is always a non-negative number) this is correct.
Portability is something else :)

Comment: `sqrt(x*x)` results in the absolute value of x.

Comment: But it's unnecessary, not useful in the solution.

Comment: Ah, I see, using `$i < 1 && $i > -1`  like in Jeff Schallers answer is better!